# iOS Visual Studio Cordova app build but won't automatically run

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My little test cordova app builds and installs fine through the vs-mda-remote tool but when it comes to run on my device it won't do it automatically.  If I time it right an manually launch it on my phone the VS debugger kicks in fine etc.

I see this in the console window on my mac where vs-mda-remote is running...

> Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue. GET
>   /build/tasks/356 200 0ms - 5.04kb GET /build/tasks/356/log 200 3ms GET
>   /files/356/cordovaApp/plugins/ios.json 200 3ms - 190b Downloading
>   build 356 ... Downloaded build 356 GET /build/356/download 200 23ms
>   Install build 356 ... GET /build/356/deploy 200 2809ms - 5.08kb Run
>   build 356 ... [TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of
>   undefined] GET /build/356/run 404 2464ms - 2b Debug build 356 ...
>   Running command 'ios_webkit_debug_proxy -c null:9221,:9222-9322' GET
>   /build/356/debug 200 7ms - 5.08kb
>
> Looking around it seems this line is the culprit...
>
> [TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined]

...trouble is since the build goes ok I can't find any problems in the build log, any ideas anybody, would be working perfect otherwise!

Comment: Ok, little more info, the above problem is present when trying on my iPhone 6 BUT it works fine on my iPad Mini (latest model).  Both are running iOS 8.2, thinking about resetting my iPhone but not sure that will help as can't understand what the problem might be or if its on the mac end, any help would be good please.

Comment: I zapped my mac and reset it back up (its only used as a build machine) and still the same problem exists so its looking like either something on my iPhone 6 or iPhone 6's in general, anybody else got app firing up fine using their iPhone 6?

Comment: Hummm, so I reset my iPhone now as well, everything works ok, just restoring for a backup and see if it still works....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, backup restored but I didn't restore my apps as there was a fair few that don't get used anyway.  I've tested again and its working fine, don't know what the issue was but it was local to the iPhone, hope that helps somebody else.

Comment: Hello, did you still had this problem since then? I'm having the same issue for a while now and I hope to get to know the root cause of it.